# Empty .prof file with crashing Haskell program (on Windows)

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I'm trying to diagnose an infinite loop in my program by using profiling. Because I have to abort the program part way through with Ctrl-C the .prof file remains empty. From what I've read, the .prof file should still work if the program crashes.

To test if it was the configuration of my specific program I wrote this:

```
module Main (
    main
) where


testInf = map (+1) [1..]

main = do
    print (show testInf)
```

I'm using Leksah and the configuration produces the following .cabal file:

```
name: tests
version: 0.0.1
cabal-version: >=1.2
build-type: Simple
license: AllRightsReserved
license-file: ""
description:  
data-dir: ""

executable tests
    build-depends: base -any
    main-is: Main.hs
    buildable: True
    hs-source-dirs: src
    ghc-options: -prof -auto-all
```

I then execute the program by running `tests +RTS -p`. When I terminate the program with Crl-C the .prof file is 0kb. If I change the program so it doesn't run infinitely it produces a full .prof file once it finishes.

**Other details**

- Cabal: `using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library`
- GHC: `Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.4.1`

Comment: Note: program crashes `/=` sending an interrupt signal using `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: True, though eventually the program crashes from an out of memory error - and the result is still the same. If anyone out there has an answer... it would be handy to know if there is a solution to this.

Comment: Perhaps you want to compile with -xc to get a stack trace when it dies? https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-options-debugging

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I ran my program through `systemctl`.

I sent in a `SIGTERM` signal and got an empty `*.prof` file back.

However sending in `SIGINT` signal gives me my `.prof` file.

Doing a bit of digging in GHC's signal handling:
https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/posix/Signals.c#L510-528

This tells us how `SIGINT` is handled:

```
 * SIGINT handler.
 *
 * We like to shutdown nicely after receiving a SIGINT, write out the
 * stats, write profiling info, close open files and flush buffers etc.
```

And also:

```
So the first ^C tries to exit the program
    // cleanly, and the second one just kills it.
```

So if you press `^C (SIGINT)` once, and the program has yet to exit, it is probably still writing to your `*.prof` file + doing other cleanup. The second `^C (SIGINT)` just terminates and leaves you with an empty `*.prof` file.